# Sending multiple values with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

I have two values I want to send but I couldn't figure it out.

Im currently sending 1 value like that:

JS:

```
req.open('POST', '../Ajax/doc.php?id=' + id, true);
req.send();
```

PHP:

```
$id = $_REQUEST["id"];
```

And now I have another value id2 which I want to send in the same way..

Thanks

Comment: `req.open('POST', '../Ajax/doc.php?id=' + id  + '&id2=' + id2, true);`

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you're sending data in via the URL and not via the request body?

Comment: @radovix Make sure you're encoding the data for the URL, with `encodeURIComponent()`!!

Comment: Of course that data should be encoded. I was just showing the obvious thing - how to add another param to query.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using post, the `SEND` function accepts the query string as a parameter. Then just replace my `var2` with what it is you are trying to send and use `POST` in `PHP` to make it easier for you to know the array to use for POST submissions.

```
const data = {
  id: 123,
  var2: 987,
  foo: 'bar',
}

req.open('POST', '../Ajax/doc.php', true)
req.send(
  Object.keys(data)
    .map(key => encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[key]))
    .join('&')
)
```

**PHP**

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$var2 = $_POST["var2"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send multiple value using FormData.

```
function send() {
    var uri = "your_url";
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var fd = new FormData();
    xhr.open("POST", uri, true);
    fd.append('title', 'Hello World');
    fd.append('content', 'Just Hello World');
    // Initiate a multipart/form-data upload
    xhr.send(fd);
}
window.onload = function () {
    btn_send = document.querySelector('#btn-click');
    btn_send.addEventListener('click', function () {
        send();
    })
}
```